# Is there a better way to do mappings with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am mapping some human-input text to part names today, and came across a case that might be of general interest.  Here is the human-input text:

Seat (Dis.)

Disc seat

seats

Seat (Suc.)

Suct seat

The two parts names to map to are `SEAT, DISCHARGE` and `SEAT, SUCTION`.  We will also map the ambiguous `seats` to `SEAT, DISCHARGE`.  The reason for using a regex is that we can anticipate new cases in the future such as `discharge seat` etc.

So currently I am tackling this with two `search()` calls like this pseudocode:

if `[Ss][Ee][Aa][Tt]` matches input name:

if `[Ss][Uu][Cc]` matches input name, part is `SEAT, SUCTION`
  else part is `SEAT, DISCHARGE`

Is there a better way to do this kind of mapping?  Better would mean: more compact code, easier to tweak to handle new cases, or a better probability to handle more cases without code modification.

Comment: In perl you can make a whole regex case insensitive by using the "i" option. I'm not a python guy but I would assume it's the same, though I'm not sure how to add options. That would change it so you could just search for "seat" or "suc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than look for all permutations of uppercase/lowercase letters, try just lowercasing the string and searching for the lowercase version.

```
linput = input.lower()
if 'seat' in linput:
    if 'suc' in linput:
        return 'SEAT, SUCTION'
    else:
        return 'SEAT, DISCHARGE'
```

I'm not sure in this case that a regex is warranted, unless you have more examples of strings you need to match. However, if you *really want* to do it that way, you can also make the regex call case insensitive by passing the `re.I` flag to any of the regex functions.

Comment: Yup, about 95% of my mappings are better done directly with Python.  re.I simplifies the regex's where needed too.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a list like this:

```
products = [
    [ "seat",
       [
          ["suc", "SEAT, SUCTION"],
          [None, "SEAT, DISCHARGE"]
       ]
    ]
]
```

and then implement the search function like this:

```
def search(text, products):
    for product in products:
        if re.search(product[0], text, re.IGNORECASE):
            for item in product[1]:
                if not item[0]:
                    return item[1]
                if re.search(item[0], text, re.IGNORECASE):
                    return item[1]
```

In fact, it might be worth implementing the list as a recursive data structure, and the function as a recursive function.  That is, each item in the list is of the form

```
[ pattern, data ]
```

where `data` is either the data to be returned if the pattern matches, or a list in the same form.  Then the search function becomes:

```
def search(text, items):
    for item in items:
        if item[0] == None or re.search(item[0], text, re.IGNORECASE):
            if type(item[1]) == type(str()):
                return item[1]
            return search(text, item[1])
```

Comment: Great idea, that recursive search is extremely compact and powerful.  In fact using it plus putting the data in an xml file would reduce the necessary code to just this function, as the logic is encoded in the data.

Comment: It would.  But - and I say this as a guy whose affection for XML borders on the irrational at times - you could just keep the data in a .py file and import it rather than writing code to parse and interpret an XML file.